# Objects on the Same Line without Losing positions?

Tags: html, css, navigation, line, banner

I am trying to put two banners on top of a navigation bar with everything nicely centered. I can get the two banners to nicely sit by one another but when I make the browser window smaller the first banner goes on top of the second!

Is there a code where I can prevent this? If so please let me know.

This is what I have so far:

```
<center>  
<a href="loanworkout.org">
    <img width="200" height="60" src="header-2.gif">
</a>
<a href="htpp://www.modifyloan.net">
    <img width="660" height="60" src="loansafe_728x90.gif">
</a> 
<BR>
```

Comment: You're always better off posting code to go with your problem, otherwise it's difficult to tell what it could be.

Comment: Ok so here is the code to the two banners and the navbar follows.

<center>

  <a href="http://www.loanworkout.org"><img width="200" height="60" src="header-2.gif"></a><a 

href="htpp://www.modifyloan.net"><img width="660" height="60" src="loansafe_728x90.gif"></a>
<BR>

Comment: And if you post your code in your question (use the 'edit' link, below the text of your question) we can understand it a little better. Probably.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a min-width on the container of the banners.

Edit based on your comment:

```
<center> <!-- *shudder* -->
    <div style="min-width: 860px;"> <!-- inline only for example purposes -->
        <a href="loanworkout.org">
            <img width="200" height="60" src="header-2.gif">
        </a>
        <a href="htpp://www.modifyloan.net">
            <img width="660" height="60" src="loansafe_728x90.gif">
        </a> 
    </div> <!-- ditch the BR -->
    ... 
</center>
```

Comment: Woot! Very HTML4-ish <center> tag. :D

Comment: Yeah; but don't pretend like you don't feel dirty now... =)

Comment: You like that hah.

OK maybe I'm not being clear.

This is what I want it to look like:

<----Banner 1----><----Banner 2---->
<-------------navbar--------------->

See everything is centered and looking nice...

then when I reduce the size of the window it looks like this.

<----Banner 1----> <- See how Banner 1 ends up on Banner 2.  
<----Banner 2---->
<-------------navbar--------------->

Even with the code posted by blu I seem to be having some problems.

Comment: I had the width wrong.  The min-width has to be at least the width of the two elements, I had 800, not 860.  If your images have borders on them, those need to be in the number too.

Comment: LOL Ok guy i'm going to put EVERYTHING in my wordpress so you can see it for yourself. My Site www.gangstatattoos.net. I placed the code in the wp_head section of my custom_functions.php